# CSS styling to show end of single text string

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a long text string. How do I get all the text to show on one line and with a certain width, but limit what is shown to the end of the string?

```css
.demo {
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">hello this is a string</p>
```

Here it shows the beginning of the string and cuts off the end, but I need it to show the end and cut off the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.demo {
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">hello this is a string</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a flex solution without changing direction:

```css
.demo {
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">hello this is a string</p>
```

Comment: this seems actually like the only valid answer. `direction: rtl;` has very nasty side effects with something like paths, causing: `/abcde` to be `abcde/`.

Comment: Can you give some advise on how to add an elipsis at the beginning of the text that has been cut? I'd like to see `...o this is a string`

Answer (score 4):

If you want the end of the string to show and hide the beginning, you can add the `direction:rtl;` property.

```css
.demo {
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

```html
<p class="demo">hello this is a string</p>
```

Comment: Asking out of curiosity... Are there any consequences of changing the `direction` that's worth keeping in mind here? In what way will this affect accessibility, e.g. screen readers?

Comment: @agrm good question and the answer is yes there is some consequences. The easiest example to show this is adding a `.` at the end of the string :) so this works but we need to pay attention to some cases

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's an interesting observation. Although if there are only (more or less) visual consequences, like the alignment of text and the position of the ending punctuation, that's a low cost that is not too hard to account for. If there are other effects behind the scenes, like screen readers hickups or phone numbers being altered etc (what do I know?), that's something I'd like to know before using `direction:rtl` :o)