# Viewing only the last line of text with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to just view the end of a potentially large piece of text where everything above the last line is cut off. This text is just one long string so splitting it on `\n` or something won't work.

Ideally I would use something like `-webkit-line-clamp` but, from what I can tell that only truncates text. I realise a lot of people will say that this is a JS issue rather than CSS but I'm trying to make this reactive and I think most JS solutions will look janky when resizing the page, however I'm very willing to be shown that I'm wrong on that!

Comment: Are you trying to  do this in any framework, or just plain HTML, and CSS

Comment: @Gopikrishna using less, html, handlebars and ajax

Comment: The numbers shouldn't matter, I want to display 1 line whatever the width of the element like with line clamping @Yogi

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481284/css-styling-to-show-end-of-single-text-string

Comment: You should provide actual code you tried (perhaps as a snippet)   Perhaps review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display only the last line, then apply `position: absolute;` to the text. But you need to know the `line-height` so that the `height` of the block is not `0`. For this you can add one character and hide it. Something like this:

```css
.wrapp {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.wrapp:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.text{
  position: absolute;
  inset: auto 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS grid can solve this:

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  height: 1lh; /* height of one line */
  overflow: hidden;
  place-content: end;
  font-size: 28px;
}
/* fallback if lh is not supported */
@supports not (height:1lh) {
  .box {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
  }
}

p {
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin quis arcu mattis, eleifend arcu in, pharetra dui. Ut maximus elit sapien, vel interdum eros consectetur eu. Maecenas non fermentum massa. Aenean ut mauris libero. Integer consequat at est non condimentum. Nunc ac convallis sem. Proin aliquet malesuada elit et imperdiet. Phasellus ornare vel nulla a euismod. Integer nec purus porta leo faucibus vehicula.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, is there a way to force it to be a full line, or am I asking too much?

Comment: @MarkMcLean what do you mean full line?

Comment: To use your snippet as an example: rather than the viewable text being just 'vehicula' it would fill the full lines width with the rest of the text

Comment: @MarkMcLean what "rest of the text"? you have a multi-line text and I am showing the last line. In the snippet it contains 'vehicula" but it can be anything, resize the screen to see different results